# Is there an "etw." that shows grammatical case?

Tags: single-word-request, preposition, learning

I've been learning verbs and their prepositions with a list like this:

- sich mit jdm. treffen
- sich über jdn. ärgern
- sich von jdm. trennen

*Jemanden/jemandem* are great for this purpose, since I can learn the phrase in a form that is close to actual usage, while still learning the correct case after the preposition. However, there are a couple of verbs that just aren't person-verbs. Such as:

- sich an etw. erinnern
- sich von etw. erholen
- sich an etw. gewöhnen
- jdn. etw. fragen

Unfortunately, the case is not apparent in the above sentences. My question is: **Which word could I use instead of *etwas* for the latter cases, such that the grammatical case is apparent?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can use the forms of jemand anyway. Duden has

> sich an etwas oder jemanden gewöhnen

as example for gewöhnen.

> Du kannst dich auch an jemanden erinnern oder dich von jemandem erholen.

It may not make sense for certain verbs, but does that matter? Just personify etwas ;)

Comment: Well, the phrases' making sense would certainly help my learning.

Comment: @Tim: Of course. But the three examples you gave actually make sense with jemand :)

Comment: Ok, you're right :) But there ought to be examples that don't. Feel free to edit in a better example.

Comment: @Tim: I can't currently think of one. At least from a grammatical point of view, they all sound just right to me... As I said, personifying something Just Works[TM] for the ones I can think of, at least for me ;)

Comment: I'll accept this because that's what I ended up doing. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Many dictionaries just explicitly mark the case by using *A* and *D*, as in

> - sich erinnern *an + A*
> - sich erholen *von + D*

I'm afraid that's as elegant as it gets. I mean, if there *were* a convenient single-word replacement for *etwas*, certainly every dictionary and its grandma would be using it by now.

Answer (score 2):

You could also just use the noun “Etwas” instead and add an article in front of it. For example:

- sich an das Etwas erinnern
- sich von einem Etwas erholen
- sich an das Etwas erinnern
- jemanden ein Etwas fragen

Granted the last ones doesn’t make that much sense, but it still works.

Also just in case you need it:

```
Nominativ: das/ein   Etwas
Genitiv:   des/eines Etwas
Dativ:     dem/einem Etwas
Akkusativ: das/ein   Etwas
```

Answer (score 1):

All verbs you mentioned can be used with both persons and things, except *sich mit jdm. treffen*, which can only be used with persons. So in your example you can still use *jdn./jdm.*

Also, at the moment I can't think of any verb that can only be used with things and requires the use of a case other than Akkusativ. This means you should be fine with using *jdn./jdm./jds.*

Comment: Meet the robot! :)